# Display saved option in the form

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In the `options.html` i have an input, where user fill their API keys, like

```
<label>
Input your API Key
<input type="text" id="wptk">
</label>
```

In the `options.js` there is a piece of code, which is saving it into storage, like with

```
function save_options() {
  var api = document.getElementById('wptk').value;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
    savedApi: api,
  }, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'OK! API Key saved!';
    setTimeout(function() {
      status.textContent = '';
    }, 10000);
  });
}

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save_options);
document.getElementById('wptk').value = api
```

It works everything, no problem. But, nevertheless the key is saved, if user looks at options twice, the form (input) is empty.

How could i display the string in the form always after it was saved?

Comment: A shot into dark: `document.getElementById('wptk').value = api` at the end of your function.

Comment: @reporter maybe i'm wrong with implementation place, but doesn't work for me for the moment. I've put it into `options.js`, at the end? No, with or without `;` - after opening options again the input is empty:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to get saved value of `savedApi` from storage and set as your field value. See below example code.

```
function restore_options() {  
    chrome.storage.sync.get({"savedApi": ''}, function(items) {
      document.getElementById('wptk').value = items.savedApi;
    });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
```

Comment: yeah! i thought it should have something to do with `chrome.storage.sync.get` - but the solution is from you:)

Comment: Great! All the best @ChillyBang